# Showing a ModalPopupExtender control when an UpdateProgress control is activated

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to show a ModalPopupExtender when an UpdateProgress control is activated. I managed this by putting a ModalPopupExtender within a UpdateProgress and then setting the ModalPopupExtender to always show in the page load. However this messes up the tabbing on the page which isn't an option. Any suggestions?

Comment: please have a look on my post here !!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21061411/update-progress-gif-image-cant-be-displayed-when-i-click-on-a-button-in-modal-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is a modal update progress indicator, I'd recommend the link below as it works quite well. The answer to your actual question, I'm sad to say I don't know.

[Modal Update Progress](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/archive/2008/03/13/Modal-UpdateProgress-for-UpdatePanel-Revisited.aspx)